# Design a decoder with unknown number of inputs using verilog

Tags: ruby, for-loop, verilog

Here is my problem.
I have unknown number of inputs (all with 3-bit wide), depending on the system configuration. I want to design a decoder to select the input with largest value as the output. So I am using embedded ruby here, so that the configuration can be passed to RTL.
Here is my design:

Code:

```
module decoder
(
<%  (1...NUM_INPUT).each do |i| -%>
     input      [2:0]  freq_<%=i%>,  
<% end -%>
     output    [2:0]  decoded_freq        
)
<%  (1...NUM_INPUT-1).each do |i| -%>
     wire      [2:0]  x<%=i%>,
<% end -%>

  integer i;
//decode logic below
  assign x1 = (freq_1 > freq_2)? freq_1:freq_2;  //compare the first two inputs and select the bigger one
  for (i=1; i<NUM_INPUT-1;i++)                   //for-loop to do the rest
       x<%=i+1%> = (x<%=i%> > freq_<%=i+2%>)? x<%=i%>:freq_<%=i+2%>;
  assign decoded_freq = x<%=NUM_INPUT-1%>;
endmodule
```

Will this work? I am not sure about the for-loop here. Is it going to work as I want? Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Wow what is going on here?  I don't know Ruby, but that just looks really ugly.  Anyway, if you want to synthesize something that has some "unknown" number of inputs, the number of inputs needs to be known before you synthesize.  You can't dynamically create signals in an FPGA, it all needs to be there when it gets programmed.

Comment: It is clear that you have not tried using ruby to parse the file. The last for-loop will not unravel and you have Verilog typos.  What version of the IEEE standard are you trying to follow? You can achieve the functionality with out embedded ruby. (Hint: use parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Excellent using erb for templating verilog. `NUM_INPUT` would be defined and then the verilog generated, I think this adds to the scalability and reuse code.

New tools can support multi-dimension ports I have found it to be unreliable with some tools though, ie `input [31:0] data [9:0]`.

There is a ruby gem designed for parsing files like this [RubyIt](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_it);

Just to mention you have used `1...NUM` the `...NUM` mean until NUM-1, you would normally use `0...NUM` to imply NUM iterations or `1..NUM` to start numbering from 1.

The for loop you have used is a verilog style but then you have used embedded ruby for some of the variables.

Some thing like this might be better:

```
<% NUM_INPUT = 3 %>
module decoder
(
  <%  (1..NUM_INPUT).each do |i| -%>
  input      [2:0]  freq_<%=i%>,  
  <% end -%>
  output     [2:0]  decoded_freq        
);
<%  (1..NUM_INPUT).each do |i| -%>
wire      [2:0]  x<%=i%>;
<% end -%>

//decode logic below
assign x1 = (freq_1 > freq_2)? freq_1:freq_2;  //compare the first two inputs and select the bigger one
<%# Ruby comment, for loop to create the others %>
<%  (2..NUM_INPUT).each do |i| -%>
assign x<%=i%> = (x<%=i-1%> > freq_<%=i%>)? x<%=i-1%>:freq_<%=i%>;
<% end %>
```

I called this decoder.rv and ran it created decoder.v with

```
gem install ruby_it

ruby_it -f test.rv
```

The Generated file:

```
module decoder
(
  input      [2:0]  freq_1,  
  input      [2:0]  freq_2,  
  input      [2:0]  freq_3,  
  output     [2:0]  decoded_freq        
);
wire      [2:0]  x1;
wire      [2:0]  x2;
wire      [2:0]  x3;

//decode logic below
assign x1 = (freq_1 > freq_2)? freq_1:freq_2;  //compare the first two inputs and select the bigger one

assign x2 = (x1 > freq_2)? x1:freq_2;
assign x3 = (x2 > freq_3)? x2:freq_3;
```

Comment: There are still Verilog syntax errors. Needs a semicolon after the first close parenthesis. The wire declarations need to be terminated by a semicolon instead of a comma. `integer i;` should be be removed because it is no longer used.

Comment: Your correct @Greg, I was concentrating on getting the ruby to parse. Will update.